# Azure DevOps run a step only on certain days

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

For Azure build pipelines, is there any way to specify a condition to run a certain step on specific days of a week?

Our requirement is run certain security scans only on one day in a week instead of running them during each build. Though the step can be excluded from CI builds run for pushes to branches using the usual conditions, I am not able to figure out how do we allow it to run only on a certain day.

Comment: To the build pipeline have another scheduled triggers unless this specific day or only this?

Comment: But I just need to include/exclude a task depending on the weekday. Other steps i.e., the build should run on CI mode.

Comment: I understand, if the build is CI build and only in specific day you have schedule trigger you can achieve the goal easily.

Comment: I think I am getting your point now. Just by adding this condition - and(always(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')). Correct?

Comment: Yes! exactly :)

Comment: Thank you very much! If you could add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You're welcome! I added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the schedule build is the only schedule build you can add a custom condition to tun the task only in this build:

```
and(always(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'Schedule'))
```